# Can Bayesian statistical models reproduce the results of frequentist ones by choosing parameters a certain way?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, bayesian, mathematical-statistics, modeling, frequentist

I am just starting to learn about Bayesian statistics, so forgive me if this is a basic question.

For Bayesian counterparts of classical frequentist methods (such as linear regression, ANOVA, t-tests, mixed effects models, ...) is it ever possible to reliably choose priors or other model parameters to replicate the results of frequentist tests?

More precisely, are there any known theorems of the form "If <...conditions...>, then one can always choose the priors (or other parameters) of Bayesian model $X$ to deliver point estimates that are identical to frequentist model $Y$'s estimates."?

Is finding generalizations like this an active topic of research?
Edit: What keywords would be useful to search for references on this topic?

([This question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/298057/attempting-to-compare-bayesian-and-frequentist-mixed-effects-models) has an example of a mixed-effects model where a particular choice of prior yielded point estimates that are close to the frequentist ones.)

Comment: Point estimates by themself are neither frequentist or Bayesian, so the question is not really well defined. For example the maximum likelihood estimator have known frequentist *properties* (bias, efficiency, etc.), but is also closely related to Bayesian statistics (e.g. it is the same as the posterior mode when the prior is uniform). People do study those relations in a more broad sense, if you google for example "Frequentist properties of Bayesian methods" you will find many references.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying! I will try that search term.